# Clase AsyncTask en Java android con sus metodos no completa el proceso

Tags: java, android, hilos, android-asynctask

Tengo un proceso que quiero que se ejecute en segundo plano , funciona pero al finalizar quiero que pase a la siguiente activity pero no lo hace, me da una pantalla negra y cuando finaliza la tarea pasa al activity:
dentro de la clase tengo varios ciclos for que se ejecutan uno tras otro:
aqui mi codigo:

```
class pruebaAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inicia",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url = "http://101.168.101.80/tablets/catalogos.php?imei=" + getIMEINumber();
            RequestQueue cola = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsTotal       = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray jaPaises       = jsTotal.getJSONArray("paises");
                                JSONArray jaProcedencia  = jsTotal.getJSONArray("procedencia");
                                JSONArray jaClave        = jsTotal.getJSONArray("clave");
                                JSONArray jaDepartamento = jsTotal.getJSONArray("departamento");
                                JSONArray jaMunicipio    = jsTotal.getJSONArray("municipio");
                                JSONArray jaCanton       = jsTotal.getJSONArray("canton");
                                JSONArray jaCaserio      = jsTotal.getJSONArray("caserio");
                                JSONArray jaTablet       = jsTotal.getJSONArray("tablet");
                                JSONArray jaInstitucion  = jsTotal.getJSONArray("institucion");
                                JSONArray jaTipo         = jsTotal.getJSONArray("tipoEstablecimiento");
                                JSONArray jaEst          = jsTotal.getJSONArray("establecimiento");


                                for (int i = 0; i <jaPaises.length() ; i++) {
                                    JSONObject joPais = jaPaises.getJSONObject(i);
                                    saveCoutry(joPais.getLong("id"), joPais.getString("nombre"),joPais.getInt("activo"));
                                }


                                for (int j = 0; j < jaProcedencia.length() ; j++) {
                                    JSONObject joProcedencia = jaProcedencia.getJSONObject(j);
                                    saveProcedencia(joProcedencia.getLong("id"), joProcedencia.getString("nombre"));
                                }

                                for (int k = 0; k <jaClave.length() ; k++) {
                                    JSONObject joClave = jaClave.getJSONObject(k);
                                    saveClave(joClave.getLong("id"),joClave.getInt("id_departamento"),joClave.getInt("id_municipio"),
                                            joClave.getInt("correlativo"),joClave.getString("clave"),joClave.getLong("id_procedencia"));
                                }
                                for (int l = 0; l < jaDepartamento.length() ; l++) {
                                    JSONObject joDepto = jaDepartamento.getJSONObject(l);
                                    saveDepartamento(joDepto.getLong("id"),joDepto.getString("nombre"),joDepto.getLong("id_pais"));
                                }
                                for (int m = 0; m <jaMunicipio.length() ; m++) {
                                    JSONObject joMpo = jaMunicipio.getJSONObject(m);
                                    int  id_depto_apoyo;
                                    if (!joMpo.isNull("id_depto_apoyo")) {
                                        id_depto_apoyo = joMpo.getInt("id_depto_apoyo");
                                    }else{
                                        id_depto_apoyo =0;
                                    }
                                    saveMunicipio(joMpo.getLong("id"),joMpo.getString("nombre"),joMpo.getLong("id_departamento"), id_depto_apoyo);
                                }
                                for (int n = 0; n <jaCanton.length() ; n++) {
                                    JSONObject joCanton = jaCanton.getJSONObject(n);
                                    saveCanton(joCanton.getLong("id"),joCanton.getString("nombre"),joCanton.getLong("id_municipio"));
                                }
                                for (int o = 0; o <jaCaserio.length() ; o++) {
                                    JSONObject joCaserio = jaCaserio.getJSONObject(o);
                                    int  id_depto_apoyo;
                                    if (!joCaserio.isNull("id_depto_apoyo")) {
                                        id_depto_apoyo = joCaserio.getInt("id_depto_apoyo");
                                    }else{
                                        id_depto_apoyo =0;
                                    }
                                    int  bandera;
                                    if (!joCaserio.isNull("bandera")) {
                                        bandera = joCaserio.getInt("bandera");
                                    }else{
                                        bandera =0;
                                    }
                                    savecaserio(joCaserio.getLong("id"),joCaserio.getString("nombre"),joCaserio.getLong("id_canton"),
                                            id_depto_apoyo,bandera);
                                }
                                for (int q = 0; q <jaInstitucion.length() ; q++) {
                                    JSONObject joIns =  jaInstitucion.getJSONObject(q);
                                    saveInstitucion(joIns.getLong("id"),joIns.getString("nombre"));
                                }
                                for (int r = 0; r <jaTipo.length() ; r++) {
                                    JSONObject joTipo = jaTipo.getJSONObject(r);
                                    saveTipoestablecimiento(joTipo.getLong("id"),joTipo.getString("nombre"),joTipo.getLong("id_institucion"));
                                }
                                saveMinsal();
                                for (int s = 0; s <jaEst.length() ; s++) {
                                    JSONObject joEst = jaEst.getJSONObject(s);
                                    long  id_municipio;
                                    if (!joEst.isNull("id_municipio")) {
                                        id_municipio = joEst.getLong("id_municipio");
                                    }else{
                                        id_municipio =0;
                                    }

                                    saveEstablecimiento(joEst.getLong("id"),joEst.getString("nombre"),joEst.getString("latitud"),
                                            joEst.getString("longitud"),id_municipio,joEst.getInt("id_establecimiento_padre"),
                                            joEst.getInt("id_tipo_establecimiento"));

                                }

                                for (int p = 0; p <jaTablet.length() ; p++) {
                                    JSONObject joTablet = jaTablet.getJSONObject(p);
                                    saveTablet(joTablet.getLong("id"),joTablet.getLong("id_sibasi"),joTablet.getString("codigo"),joTablet.getString("imei"));
                                }


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();                        }


                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            cola.add(stringRequest);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean abolean) {
        //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (abolean){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno por si a alguien mas le pasa, la situaion era que Volley trabaja en un hilo aparte de la interfaz de usuario por lo tanto no habia necesidad de crear una tarea asyncrona ya que volley se ejecuta de forma asincrona:
al final he ejecutado todo el proceso en un metodo voi y ha funcionado.